# Update value Ad attribute to null or empty get errror?

Tags: c#

Here code to update mail, department, title and mobile to null or empty value of AD user.

```
            var adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(ConnectHelper.ContxEntry);
            adSearch.Filter = "samAccountName=" + "....";
            var result = adSearch.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                user.Properties["mail"].Value = null;
                user.Properties["Department"].Value = null;
                user.Properties["Title"].Value = null;
                user.Properties["mobile"].Value = null;
                user.CommitChanges();
            }
```

Error: 
"The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid."

How can i set Value of some properties to null or empty???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using :

```
user.Properties["mail"].Clear()
```

instead of :

```
user.Properties["mail"].Value = null;
```